# Order Cancelled (Google Developer Console)

Tags: android, google-developers-console

In my Google Developer Console under "Order Management" I have a lot of cancelled order like that:

> Order history:
>
> Jan 18 2017 5:13 PM
>   Payment pending
>   You received a new order.
>
> Jan 18 2017 5:13 PM
>   Cancelling
>   Process for cancelling the order was initiated.
>
> Jan 18 2017 5:13 PM
>   Cancelled
>   The order was cancelled.

This is the history of my in-app purchase order.

**Is that Normal**? Maybe this happen every time a user click "buy in app-purchase" and than came back?

Someone know when this happen? Thanks

Comment: I've had these periodically come up for IAPs for a while now (not just recently). For example, I had one user who made 2 successful orders, got the 3rd order cancelled (there was no charge, just a payment pending and then cancellation), and succeeded in getting the 4th order - all of them within 3 mins. How does the 3rd order get cancelled by the user? I have the same question as you do.

Comment: Just bringing up the purchase dialog and dismissing it wouldn't cause a cancellation, but pressing on Buy and then cancelling it might result in the problem

Comment: This issue is normal or not, because i am having nearly 80% of payment declined, which seems really lot, is it normal? I mean if user cancels it by himself then Ok, but if not than that's really sad

Comment: This issue still occurs, does any one have any idea why it happens or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I just got six of these in a row.  All within a space of ten minutes, and each one was canceled within one minute of the order being received.  And all, apparently, from the same user.

Google's new interface removes some information that used to be provided to developers in its older interface.  We no longer receive a zip code for the order - just the nation from which it originated.  And if an order failed because of a rejected credit card or due to cancellation by the user, it apparently does not distinguish between such events, instead telling us simply that "The order was cancelled."

It does appear that the User Latest Orders section shows you all other orders for a developer's own products that came from the user associated with the order being viewed.  That is useful information as it can tell you how that user progressed from buying one product to buying another one, showing the synergy between product lines, and giving an indication of the success of cross-promoting products.

These six cancellations in a row cannot all be due to the user reverting the purchase, because Google only allows that to be done one time for a given product.  After that, the second purchase would be final.  But there are six total purchases for this same user, all canceled.

In the past, when using the old system that gave more information about cancellations, repeated cancellations like this were usually due to a user trying a rejected credit card more than one time, or trying more than one credit card and having all of them rejected.  I suspect that this is what is happening here, only it appears more mysterious because Google is no longer letting us know about what, specifically, caused each order to be canceled.

BTW, my six canceled orders were not in-app purchases; they were all for the same paid app.  So any problems that Google might be having with in-app payments were not the cause of my particular experience of multiple cancellations.

Comment: Update:  I just noticed this happening for a single user five times over an interval of almost a year.  This is for the same in-app payment for the same app.  I believe that in-app payments are not supposed to be cancelable, and yet this has happened five times.  Each time, it looks like this:

Sep 21 2017 11:17 PM
 
Payment pending
 
You received a new order.
Sep 21 2017 11:47 PM
 
Cancelling
 
Process for cancelling the order was initiated.
Sep 21 2017 11:47 PM
 
Cancelled
 
The order was cancelled.

Mysterious.

Comment: what is the solution for this? why order gets cancelled automatically exactly on 30 minutes of order? can you please elaborate? I have too many this type of entries on my play console.

Comment: Any solution yet? Also facing multiple "payment declined", what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

This means that "Payment was cancelled during processing by the user or due to a payment issue". You can check more information in [official documents](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2741495?hl=en).

Comment: This is inaccurate. The docs state - `Cancelled` - `Payment was cancelled during processing by the user or due to a payment issue.` So you cannot assume that this was caused by the user cancelling the order. It could also be a payment issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the buyer can cancel/revert the payment fox x minutes after buying something in the Google play store.
I have also some cancellations in my payments. But not many.

Comment: But is strange that he cancelled the order in the same minute that he do... and I have many of those. Sound strange to me

Comment: @Denny What you're saying is true for paid apps, but I don't think it applies to IAPs, based on the docs. I can't be sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Google is currently having issues with In-app purchases: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/JhGtK_pqKdA

They're charging the user but not giving the money to the developer.

Comment: Your link is right only "if you are a Supercell user who made a purchase", that's not a google problem is a Supercell error.

Comment: No. "This has also just happened to me with a different app, buying a subscription. The money has been taken but nothing else has changed, and I have received no order number, no email, no app notification, nothing."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this article](https://support.google.com/store/answer/2423477?hl=en) will help you.

It says:

> It usually takes about an hour for your order to start getting prepared for shipment. During this time the order will be listed as Pending on your order history page. If it is listed as Pending, you can cancel. You can also cancel your order if your item is not in stock.