# google developer subscription orders always payment pending then Payment declined

Tags: android, subscription

I am developer an app which which with subscription service monthly,after the 7 days free trial,I check my orders in Google Developer Console,I found most of the order status is "Payment Pending" after like two days the status change to "Payment declined".What happened? did the user canceled the subscription or what?

> Nov 4 2017 9:36 AM Payment pending You received a new order.
>
> Nov 6 2017 9:36 AM Payment declined Process for cancelling the order
>   was initiated.Reason: Payment declined.
>
> Nov 6 2017 9:41 AM Payment declined The order was cancelled.

Comment: I found the same thing. what is the reason? did you discover the matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order Cancelled (Google Developer Console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726060/order-cancelled-google-developer-console)

Comment: I am having the same issue, my paid app is published recently, no errors with merchant account all documentation is complete. Yet no customers are able to purchase the app. I am not getting very much help from google, the customer support is clueless.